# Certain conditions for primitive roots of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

> Let $a$ be a primitive root for modulo $n$. Then, $a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}\equiv-1\pmod{n}$.

I have a question for its converse. In general, its converse is false.

Is it possible to make(it means 'adding certain conditions')the converse is true?

Give some advice! Thank you!

Comment: $$\phi(n)=2^m$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, Thank you for comment. How to show that? I can't initiate